# Ao visitar medalha a formatação sua formatação fica alterada

Tags: bug, status-aceito, layout

[Na lista de medalhas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), ao clicar em uma delas para ver a sua descrição, o layout do link fica diferente:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também acontece isso no perfil:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O culpado é um genérico `a:visited { color: #666; }` no CSS, sendo herdado basicamente por qualquer link.